# Передать в AJAX функцию href кликаемой ссылки

Tags: javascript, ajax

День добрый!

Совсем новичок, во всем, что со скриптами связано, и уже голову сломал в поиске ответа вот на такой вопрос: есть сервис по поиску автозапчастей из удаленной базы на сервере поставщика, у них свое подобие api, но с ним я разобрался, и не в этом дело. А проблема в том, что реализуемый скрипт должен работать в два шага: 
 1. По введенному номеру детали определять всех производителей, у которых в каталоге есть деталь с таким номером. 
 2. Выводить информацию по выбранной детали (наличие цена и проч.).

Без ajax все работает прекрасно, но пользователю нужно совершить два перехода по ссылкам, что неудобно. Тем более, что на первом шаге уже формируются ссылки и задача заключается только в том, чтобы перейти по ним.

Итак, сначала ищем всех производителей, в каталоге которых есть деталь с введенным номером:

```
  var xmlHttp;
function showResult(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
 { 
 document.getElementById("livesearch").
 innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById("livesearch").
 style.border="0px";
 return;
 }
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
if (xmlHttp==null)
 {
 alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
 return;
 } 
var url="client/detail.php";
url=url+"?q="+str;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged ;
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged() 
{ 
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
 { 
 document.getElementById("livesearch").
 innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
 document.getElementById("livesearch").
 style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
 } 
}
function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
var xmlHttp=null;
try
 {
 // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
 xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
catch (e)
 {
 // Internet Explorer
 try
  {
  xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
 catch (e)
  {
  xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 }
return xmlHttp;
}
```

Весь detail.php выкладывать смысла нет, но ссылки формируются так:

```
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&marka_id='.$marka['id'].'"onclick="return OpenAjax()">'.$marka['name'].'</a></br>';
```

И сами ссылке на выходе имеют вот такой вид:

```
<a href="/client/detail.php?q=545&amp;sid=0.4979946280363947&amp;marka_id=127" onclick="return OpenAjax()">DBA</a>
```

Функция же `OpenAjax()` призвана вывести эту ссылку в div на странице:

```
function OpenAjax() {
var cont = document.getElementById('content');
var loading = document.getElementById('loading');
cont.innerHTML = loading.innerHTML;
var http = createRequestObject();

if( http )
{
**link="client/detail.php?q=657&marka_id=639"**
http.open("GET", link, true);

http.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
if(http.readyState == 4)
{
cont.innerHTML = http.responseText;

}
}
http.send(null);
}
return false
}
// создание ajax объекта
function createRequestObject()
{
try { return new XMLHttpRequest() }
catch(e)
{
try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP') }
catch(e)
{
try { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') }
catch(e) { return null; }
}
}
}
```

А вот и сам вопрос. Как в link подставить адрес именно той ссылки из блока, на которую нажал пользователь. Сейчас все работает, но, естественно, открывается всегда одна и та же ссылка, вне зависимости от того, какая была нажата. Как решить эту проблему? Форма живет на moyvin.ru.

Comment: @evgeniex, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, передавать значение в качестве параметра в функцию

```
Echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&marka_id='.$marka['id'].'"onclick="return OpenAjax('.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&marka_id='.$marka['id'].')">'.$marka['name'].'</a></br>';
```

Или

```
Echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&marka_id='.$marka['id'].'"onclick="return OpenAjax(this.href())">'.$marka['name'].'</a></br>';
```